# new window screenshot failed

Tags: javascript, html, window, screenshot

I am trying to screenshot page created in new window, not popup but in new tab. Code now is simple. And page can be created.
However my goal is to make Full page screenshot of it. I used in Chrome - "Full Page Screen Capture " and in Firefox top screen captures - all of them greyed out - meaning impossible to capture entire page.
[screenshot fialed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sNhhX.png)

Code:

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
  <title>New Window Screenshot</title>
</head>
<body>
<script>
function newWindow() {
    var w = window.open('', '_blank');
    w.document.write('Loading preview...');
}
</script>
    <button onclick="newWindow()">Click me</button>
</body>
</html>
```

[code](https://jsfiddle.net/amberija/7twa5jqq/)

Please, no need of html2canvas. I just need to lunch some screencapturers. And my guess, well I don't know... Please help!

Comment: I also noticed if I copy HTML and create local file with it - everything works fine. Any screecapturer works.

Comment: Same happens when hit save image from site: [link](http://www.smart-page.net/smartnormal/)